# How to use Angular JS to get values from multi-select checkbox

Tags: java, list, checkbox, angularjs, multi-select

I would like to create check box for the multiple file download purpose. There is a list of many files and each file has the checkbox for itself. I want to select 4 of them and press download button only once then all the names of the files checked will be send as a list to controller(Angular JS). But I don't have any idea about how to start it and how to send the list of parameter back to Angular JS controller.What I want to do is to send the list back to controller and call a multiple download method written in JAVA.

Comment: What have you you tried?

Comment: I have tried to bind the value I have got from JSON and set it to each checkbox. I try to tick multiple checkbox and press submit but nothing happen. I observed from Firebug and it shows that nothing send back to AngularJS controller. Actually, I try to look for the hint or the guide on how to do like that. What I have found on the internet is just update the value from checkbox in the client side but mine is sent those value(s) as a list and send back to controller which will call another method on server side...

Answer (score 7):

You can just use ng-model to assign the property to put the value in. It will automatically put it in an array. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blesh/yHd6f/)

And here's the code:

```
  <select multiple="multiple" ng-model="value"
    ng-options="option for option in ['bananas', 'rice', 'applesauce', 'toast']"></select>
  <hr/>
  value: {{value}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is closed to what I try to do. I already assigned each checkbox to hold individual value that I got from JSON. However what I need to do is click check on each button and send it back to controller not just show it in client side. Because I need to perform multiple download by checked some checkbox and press only one button to download them.

Comment: I do not quite understand why this answer is not enough for you.  You just have to put button and push event handler to access '$scope.value', don't you?  See 'ng-click' for how to add click handler if not yet.